# SQL CASE with COUNT or SUM issue

Tags: mysql, count, sum, case

I have tried some options but it simply does not work or does not fit my needs.

Its about the following SQL (This does not work but is most close to what i need):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN r.`content` LIKE '% word1 %' 
            then 1 
            else 0 
      END AS `val1`
    , CASE WHEN r.`content` LIKE '% word2 %' 
           then 1 
           else 0 
      END AS `val2`
    , CASE WHEN r.`city` LIKE 'cityname' 
           then 1 
           else 0 
      END AS `val3`
    , (`val1`+`val2`+`val3`) AS `reference_value` 
FROM `testimonials` as r 
WHERE `accepted`='1' 
ORDER BY `reference_value`
```

So basically the entry with the most points end on top. When the 3 cases match `reference_value` will have 3 points.
The code is dynamically so it can also be 4,5,6,7 or more CASEs.

I hope this makes any sense to you. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: always provide some dataset and expected results. no matter how clear you explain it "in words". have this:... wants this:... will be correctly answered in a fastest way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reuse calculated values (like `val1` in your query) in the same `SELECT` list.

Use a subquery, or repeat the CASEs to sum their values. My preference is subquery in this case, but the actual requirements and the actual execution plan (explain) can overwrite it at any time.

```
SELECT
  val1,val2,val3,
  val1+val2+val3 as reference_value
FROM (
  SELECT CASE WHEN r.`content` LIKE '% word1 %' 
            then 1 
            else 0 
      END AS `val1`
    , CASE WHEN r.`content` LIKE '% word2 %' 
           then 1 
           else 0 
      END AS `val2`
    , CASE WHEN r.`city` LIKE 'cityname' 
           then 1 
           else 0 
      END AS `val3`
  FROM `testimonials` as r 
  WHERE `accepted`='1' 
) TMP
ORDER BY `reference_value`
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I still get the error: #1054 - Unknown column 'val1' in 'field list'

Comment: Yup, I forgot to delete your original sum line. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,val1+val2+val3 AS `reference_value` FROM (
    CASE WHEN r.content LIKE '% word1 %' 
        then 1 
        else 0 
    END AS `val1`
   ,CASE WHEN r.content LIKE '% word2 %' 
       then 1 
       else 0 
   END AS `val2`
  ,CASE WHEN r.city LIKE 'cityname' 
       then 1 
       else 0 
  END AS `val3`
  ,  
  FROM `testimonials` as r 
  WHERE `accepted`='1' 
)
ORDER BY `reference_value`
```